# adding reference line in line chart based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

i have a sample of  data frame like this

[image: pic1]

i want to plot a line chart with index on x axis and amplitude on y axis for that I am using

[image: pic2]
I got a line chart but how can I add reference line to show that a quake happened at a point I am expecting a chart like this or similar

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of plotly > of 4.12.0, you can use 'add_vline' of plotly.express:
https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/

```
import plotly.express as px

data={"date":["2007-10-02 00:00:00","2007-10-02 00:00:20","2007-10-02 00:00:40","2007-10-02 00:01:00"],
    "ampli":[35,39.37,39.48,36],"quake":[np.nan,np.nan,4.3,np.nan]}



df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
df_quake = df[df['quake'].notna()]

fig2=px.line(df,x=df.index, y="ampli",title="ampli")
fig2.add_vline(x=df_quake.index, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
plotly.offline.plot(fig2, filename='test2.html')
```

Else, you can try to do something with graph_object:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly

import numpy as np


data={"date":["2007-10-02 00:00:00","2007-10-02 00:00:20","2007-10-02 00:00:40","2007-10-02 00:01:00"],
    "ampli":[35,39.37,39.48,36],"quake":[np.nan,np.nan,4.3,np.nan]}



df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
df_quake = df[df['quake'].notna()]


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["ampli"],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_quake.index, y=df_quake["ampli"],
                    mode='markers',
                    name='quake',
                    marker={'size':10}))
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='test.html')
```

result:
[image]